# How to simulate egrep with other commands?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I have to simulate `egrep` plus some options with other commands, mainly `awk`, but I don't really understand how to do it in a script. I know that `awk` recognizes regular expressions, but can it be a substitute for `egrep`?

I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: This is a very subjective question. Do you have specific tasks on hand? Can you break it down for us so that we can give a solution that matches more closely?

Comment: Its an exercise.
I have to simulate egrep [n] [v] [i] [w] [-f file].
I think i have to use something like "/reg expr goes here/".

Comment: An exercise? Are we talking `homework` here?

Comment: Which options do you need to support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Sample File Used:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
This is FirstLine
SecondLineEEE
AAAblablabla
ForthLineEEE
FifthLine
LastLine
```

#### Simulation:

#### 1. `egrep -n`

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] egrep -n 'LastLine' file
6:LastLine
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk /LastLine/'{print NR":"$0}' file
6:LastLine
```

#### 2. `egrep -v`

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] egrep -v 'LastLine' file
This is FirstLine
SecondLineEEE
AAAblablabla
ForthLineEEE
FifthLine
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '/LastLine/{next}1' file
This is FirstLine
SecondLineEEE
AAAblablabla
ForthLineEEE
FifthLine
```

**or (as pointed by Dennis in the comments)**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '!/LastLine/' file
This is FirstLine
SecondLineEEE
AAAblablabla
ForthLineEEE
FifthLine
```

#### 3. `egrep -i` (This is only in **`gnu awk`**)

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] egrep -i 'lastline' file
LastLine
[jaypal:~/Temp] gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/lastline/' file
LastLine
```

#### 4. `egrep -w` (This is only in **`gnu awk`**)

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] egrep -w 'is' file
This is FirstLine
[jaypal:~/Temp] gawk '/\<is\>/' file
This is FirstLine
```

#### 5. `egrep -f`

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
This is FirstLine
SecondLineEEE
AAAblablabla
ForthLineEEE
FifthLine
LastLine

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat patternfile
LastLine
is

[jaypal:~/Temp] egrep -f patternfile file
This is FirstLine
LastLine

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next} {for (x in a) if ($0~x) print $0}' patternfile file
This is FirstLine
LastLine
```

Comment: A closer analog to `egrep -v`: `awk '!/LastLine/`. Your `egrep -w` alternative will output false positives. It should be `awk '/\<is\>/`.

Comment: Thanks @DennisWilliamson I will add your suggestion for `egrep -v` i n the answer and **yikes** I forgot the word boundaries (my bad) :)

Comment: The meaning of `egrep -f` is to read patterns, not an awk script, from a file. This can be simulated with `awk '(NR==FNR){++a[$0]}!a[$0]' patternfile inputfile` or some such.

Comment: @tripleee Oopsie … updated the answer. I couldn't get your solution to work so I added my own. But thanks for the feedback. :)

Comment: thanks for the replies..!
is it possible to work for (re1|re2),re? and re+ too??

Comment: Yes, awk supports roughly the same regex features as egrep, you just need to put it in slash delimiters, and backslash-escape any literal slashes.